# SwiftUI Core Data save single values

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I am using CoreData in my App and want to save a single Picker value. I could create an entity with an Integer attribute and always edit the first object in the EntityList. But that doesn't sound like a clean solution.

The Picker is placed inside a settings view and has to be synced with iCloud.

Is there a simple way to do this?

This is the code. The part missing is the way how to save the Picker value.

```
@State private var PickerSelection: Int = 0
var body: some View {
        
        Picker(selection: $PickerSelection, label: Text("")) {
            Text("Selection 1").tag(1)
            Text("Selection 2").tag(2)
        }
        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        
        Button(action: {
            // Save PickerSelection
            try? viewContext.save()
        }) {
            Text("Save")
        }
}
```

Comment: Would you show your code: what to where do you want to save?

Comment: I edited the question. "// Save PickerSelection" is the place where I want to save my selected value.

Comment: You need an entity. Period.

Comment: Create a entity only once. There you can store your value.

Comment: Yes. I modified the code so that it creates an object if the .count of the entity list is 0. If it is not 0 then it will modify the first object.

Answer (score 0):

You could save it to `UserDefaults` using the [`@AppStorage`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-appstorage-property-wrapper) property wrapper.

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("selection") var selection: Int = 1

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Option number:  \(selection)")
            
            Picker("Selection of something", selection: $selection) {
                Text("Option 1").tag(1)
                Text("Option 2").tag(2)
                Text("Option 3").tag(3)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes that you are only supporting iOS 14.0+, however there are alternatives of using a custom UserDefaults wrappers.

Comment: Is it possible to sync User Defaults with iCloud?

Comment: @Kataran This is an example for saving a simple value for a `Picker`. You should have probably mentioned what it is for, and that you need to sync it with iCloud. That would require a different method AFAIK. Is this for a settings menu of some sort?

Comment: Yes I should have done that. I edited the question to be more precise.

Comment: @Kataran I see - I'll leave this answer though for anyone who doesn't need sync, as someone may find this useful in the future.